# Use NFA to express the left quotient of the language of a DFA with respect to the language of another DFA

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, finite-automata, nondeterminism

Let $\Sigma = \{a,b\}$, $L_1,L_2\subseteq \Sigma^*.$

$L_1 \triangleleft L_2 = \{w\in \Sigma^* \mid \exists v\in L_1, vw \in L_2\}$

For clarity, here is python code that shows $L_3 \triangleleft L_4$:

```python
answer = set()
L3 = {"aa", "b", "bb"}
L4 = {"a", "b", "ab", "bb", "aaa", "bbab"}
for c in L3:
    for c1 in L4:
        if c1.startswith(c):
            answer.add(c1.removeprefix(c))
print(answer)
# output: {'', 'a', 'ab', 'b', 'bab'}
```

$\mathcal{L(A_1)}$ means the language accepted by DFA $\mathcal{A_1}$.

Let $\mathcal{A_1} = \{Q_1, \Sigma, \delta_1,q_{1,0},F_1\}$,  $\mathcal{A_2}= \{Q_2, \Sigma, \delta_2,q_{2,0},F_2\}$ be 2 DFAs, how to write an NFA to accept $\mathcal{L(A_1)}\triangleleft\mathcal{L(A_2)}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### An NFA with $\epsilon$-moves

Here is an NFA with $\epsilon$-moves $\mathcal M=((Q_1\times Q_2)\sqcup Q_2, \Sigma, \delta,  (q_{1,0},q_{2,0}), F_2)$,
where $\delta$ is defined as below.
$\quad\delta((r,s), \epsilon)=\{(\delta_1(r, \sigma), \delta_2(s, \sigma))\mid \sigma\in\Sigma\}\quad\forall r\in Q_1\setminus F_1,\, \forall s\in Q_2$,
$\quad\delta((r,s), \epsilon)=\{(\delta_1(r, \sigma), \delta_2(s, \sigma))\mid \sigma\in\Sigma\}\sqcup\{s\}\quad\forall r\in F_1,\, \forall s\in Q_2$,
$\quad\delta(s,\sigma)=\{\delta_2(s,\sigma)\}\quad\forall s\in Q_2,\ \forall\sigma\in\Sigma.$

In plain words, upon an input word $w$, $\mathcal M$ will simulate $\mathcal A_1$ and $\mathcal A_2$ in parallel, as if both DFAs are given the same arbitrary input. When the simulation of $\mathcal A_1$ goes into one of its final states, $\mathcal M$ will optionally switch to continue the simulation of  $\mathcal A_2$ only and with input $w$. $\mathcal M$ accepts when the lonely simulation of $\mathcal A_2$ ends up at one of its final states.

We can prove that $\mathcal M$ accepts $\mathcal{L(A_1)}◃\mathcal{L(A_2)}$ routinely.

##### Also as an NFA

Because of [the equivalence of NFA with $\epsilon$-moves to NFA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton#Equivalence_to_NFA), the construction above can be transformed methodically to build an equivalent NFA, which is what is wanted in the question.

##### What if $\mathcal L(\mathcal A_1)$ is replaced by any language?

In fact, we can build an NFA with $\epsilon$-moves for
$$\mathcal D\triangleleft \mathcal L(\mathcal A_2) = \{w\in \Sigma^* \mid \exists v\in {\mathcal D},\ vw \in\mathcal L(\mathcal A_2)\}$$
where $\mathcal D$ is *any* language, i.e., it can be non-regular or even non-computable.

Assume $\mathcal D$ is nonempty. Let $Q_{\mathcal D}=\{\delta(q_{2,0}, v)\in Q_2\mid v\in {\mathcal D}\}$.
Define $\mathcal N=(Q\sqcup\{q_{\text{new}}\}, \Sigma, \mu, q_{\text{new}}, F_2)$, where $\mu$ is defined below.
$\quad\mu(q_{\text{new}}, \epsilon)=Q_{\mathcal D}$
$\quad\mu(q, \sigma)=\{\delta(q, \sigma)\}\quad\forall q\in Q, \forall\sigma\in\Sigma$

Thanks to $Q_{\mathcal D}$, $\mathcal N$ looks even simpler than $\mathcal M$.

We have $\mathcal L(\mathcal N)={\mathcal D}\triangleleft {\mathcal L}(\mathcal A_2)$. In particular, the right-hand side is a regular language.

Comment: Is there redundant brackets? $((\delta_1(r, \sigma), \delta_2(s, \sigma))$ or $(\delta_1(r, \sigma), \delta_2(s, \sigma))$ ?

Comment: @AsukaMinato Thanks. Updated.